Jetpack Compose make Image fill height of parent
I have a link of very wide picture and need to use it as background of view. For me is important to stick the image to the end, top and bottom of view. Since the picture is too wide, I want that it goes out of screen to the left.
I tried ConstraintLayout and Box but didn't achieve. Here is my code:
@Composable
fun TestWide2() {
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.at_blue_transparent))
) {
    val (image, content) = createRefs()
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.at_white))
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .constrainAs(image) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            },
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.at_test_wide_small),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
        alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(content) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
            .padding(bottom = 5.dp, top = 3.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Some text with unpredictable length placed on the left side of the screen",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(end = 100.dp, bottom = 2.dp),
        )
        CtaButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(
                    end = 130.dp,
                    top = 20.dp
                ),
            elevation = 0.dp,
            text = "Button",
            onPressed = {  },
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )
    }
}
}

This is what I get:

And this is what I want to achieve:

In the code example is a file from resources, but in the real code it's a URL, so I can not put it as a background of view.
Also since the text can be scaled by user, the Image and View height have to be dynamic.

Remove wrapContentHeight() from the Image and make the height fill constraints instead:
Image(
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .constrainAs(image) {
      top.linkTo(parent.top)
      end.linkTo(parent.end)
      bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)

      height = Dimension.fillToConstraints // <-- This
    },
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
    alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
)

However, you actually don't even need ConstraintLayout for this, intrinsic height will do the job too:
Box(
  modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
  Image(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .fillMaxHeight(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
    alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
  )
  Column {
    // your content
  }
}

